# Mergesort time complexity

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Using the regular mergesort algorithm for a list, say $a[1...n]$, we call the merge function to merge, mergesort($a[1...\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor]$) and mergesort($a[\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor+1...n]$). Let $T(n)$ be the time complexity for mergesort. Then, the first sublist needs $T(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)$ time and the second one needs $T(\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil)$ time. Since merge needs linear time, we have the recurrence relation for the time complexity: $T(n)=T(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)+T(\lceil\frac{n}{2} \rceil)+ O(n)$.

Am I wrong ?
If no, the answer should be $T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+O(n)$. How are the two relations the same ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, but ignoring floor and ceiling does not affect the asymptotic behavior of your recurrence, so you can consider $T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n)$ instead of $T(n) = T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + O(n)$ while still obtaining the same (asymptotic) solution.

This might feel a bit hand-wawy, but it can be justified formally using a technique known as "domain transformation".

Consider the recurrence $T(n) \le 2 T(\lceil n / 2 \rceil) + O(n)$, since $\lceil n/2 \rceil \le n/2 + 1$ we have $T(n) \le T(n/2 + 1) + O(n)$. Define $S(n) = T(n+\alpha)$ for some constant $\alpha$ to be fixed later. You have:
$$
\begin{align*}
S(n) = T(n+\alpha) &\le 2 T\left( \frac{n+\alpha}{2} +1\right) + O(n) \\
&= 2T\left(\frac{n + \alpha + 2}{2}\right) +O(n) = 2S\left(\frac{n - \alpha + 2}{2} \right) + O(n),
\end{align*}
$$
therefore we can choose $\alpha=2$ to obtain $S(n) \le 2S(n/2) + O(n)$, which has solution $S(n) = O(n \log n)$. Substituting back, we get:
$$
T(n) = S(n-2) = O( n \log n ).
$$

Comment: So in general we are using the fact that Time Complexity is an increasing sequence.  
But how $T(\frac{n}{2})$ has meaning ? I mean if $n$ is not even, what does it mean, say, time complexity of $1.5$ steps ? I think the recurrence relation should be $T(n)\leq 2T(\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil) +O(n)$, using $T(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)\leq T(\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil)$

Comment: You can define $T(n)$ on the reals, the only requirement is that when $n$ is an integer, $T(n)$ needs to be an upper bound to the time complexity of the algorithm for inputs of size $n$.